# How can I access GitHub Action environment variables within a Bash script run by the Action?

Tags: bash, github-actions

I'm not able to access environment variables defined at the top-level of a GitHub Action configuration file from within a script run by the action.

For example, given the following config file:

```
name: x-pull-request
on: pull_request
env:
  FOO: bar
jobs:
  test:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v1
      - name: does a thing
        run: ./scripts/do-a-thing.sh
```

... and the following script:

```
X=${FOO:default}
echo "X: $X" # X: default
```

The `FOO` environment variable defined in the config file is not available to the script and the default value is being used.

So, how can I access the environment variable from a Bash script run by the build step? Am I missing a prefix or something? (I know values defined in the `input` hash require you to use an `INPUT_` prefix when referencing them.)

Comment: Can you access default env vars like `GITHUB_WORKFLOW` or `GITHUB_REPOSITORY` ?

Comment: @DiegoTorresMilano No. I just tried using `GITHUB_WORKFLOW` in place of `FOO` in the example provided in my question and the default value was used.

Comment: https://help.github.com/en/actions/automating-your-workflow-with-github-actions/using-environment-variables they should work. Try printing the whole `env` instead of just echo a var.

Answer (score 9):

You can use env at [any level](https://help.github.com/en/actions/reference/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#env) also in jobs and steps.

I wrote a test action and a test script to validate it:

The action file:

```
name: Env tests
on: push

env:
  FOO_ROOT: bar on root

jobs:
  test:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    env:
      FOO_JOB: bar on job
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v1
      - name: Test envs
        run: ./env-test.sh
        env:
          FOO_STEP: bar on step
```

The script file:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

echo "FOO_ROOT: $FOO_ROOT"
echo "FOO_JOB: $FOO_JOB"
echo "FOO_STEP: $FOO_STEP"
echo " "
printenv
```

The results:

```
FOO_ROOT: bar on root
FOO_JOB: bar on job
FOO_STEP: bar on step

LEIN_HOME=/usr/local/lib/lein
M2_HOME=/usr/share/apache-maven-3.6.3
...
```

Check my [results](https://github.com/TiagoGouvea/github-actions-test/runs/618139105?check_suite_focus=true) and, in fact, I don't know why it didn't work on your side because it must work.

Comment: Thanks. This jives with the behavior I was expecting. I'll need to revisit my action and compare it to what you're doing here.

Comment: @pdoherty926 some behavior has changed just at the beginning of the GitHub Actions, some things new was implemented, I mean, in 2019 that. But probably it will work for you as expected. :)

Answer (score 6):

If some one else is searching for a solution you have to explicitly pass the environment variables to the bash script. Otherwise they are not available:

```
name: x-pull-request
on: pull_request
env:
  FOO: bar
jobs:
  test:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v1
      - name: does a thing
        run: ./scripts/do-a-thing.sh $FOO
```

and in the script you have to map the parameter to a variable.

```
X=$1
echo "X: $X" # X: default
```

Answer (score 1):

I know this is old, but I came across this while writing my own GitHub Actions code and figured I'd point out what I believe is the actual issue you're running into.

The problem is you're using the wrong syntax for default variable values.

Incorrect:

```bash
myVal=${ENV_VAL:default}
```

Correct:

```bash
# Notice the addition of the hyphen
myVal=${ENV_VAL:-default}
```

Thus, your script should use:

```bash
X=${FOO:-default}
echo "X: $X" # X: default
```

More details can be found in the [Parameter Expansion](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_02) subsection of the docs.